# What will happen when I add multiple @ComponentScan in different @Configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When using spring, I want to have a configuration structure like:

```
//package com.test
//main configuration A
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.pakcage.A", "com.common"})
public class AppA{
...
}

//package com.test
//main configuration B
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.pakcage.B", "com.common"})
public class AppB{
...
}

//package com.common
//sub configuration for common use
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.pakcage.common1", "com.package.common2"})
public class CommonConfig{
...
}
```

I can launch my Application by useing Configuration AppA or Configuration AppB, and all of them contains some common packages to scan like

> "com.pakcage.common1"/"com.package.common2"

, I want to put it into a single configuration.

I want to ask

1. What will happen when I put multiply `@ComponentScan`, there will be a combination of all of these `@ComponenScan`?
2. Is there some source code reference to read about how this happen?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, all the packages defined by any `@ComponentScan` will be scanned.
2. Yes, spring framework is opensource. You can access the sources [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework).